# Обновить ViewModel / RecyclerViewAdapter LifeCycle

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, viewmodel

При инициализации viewModel использую кастомный Factory с передачей в конструктор аргумента.

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel { ...
```

В активити инициализирую:

```
private void initializeViewModel() {
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders
            .of(this, new ViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), argsSelect))
            .get(MyViewModel.class);

    viewModel.getLogsList().observe(this, new Observer<List<DebugMessage>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<DebugMessage> debugMessages) {
            logAdapter.addItems(debugMessages);
        }
    });
}
```

Дело в том, что мой **argsSelect** изменяется real time. Как мне обновить вывод в моем ***RecyclerView*** данных с новым select на основании текущих аргументов.

Comment: Если обернуть `argSelect` в `MutableLiveData` можно подписаться так же, как на `getLogsList().observe(...)`